# Duplicated output when using: `find pwd .`

Tags: bash, find

I am trying to find some files and get the absolute path.

If I use: `` find `pwd` . ``

I get the files with absolute path but I also get them from `./`

If I use: `` find `pwd` `` then I just get the files once.

Why Is that happening ?

Comment: What do you expect that to do?

Comment: Hint: What would `find . .` do? Or `find / /`?

Comment: BTW, it's much more efficient to run `find "$PWD"` than ```find `pwd` ```, as the latter forks off a subshell, which has a substantial performance cost.

Comment: Going forward, questions about "why do UNIX tools work as they do?" are probably a better fit for [unix.se] rather than StackOverflow -- our scope here is limited to problems "[unique to software development](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)", and `find` has a multitude of uses beyond development/scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments given to `find` which precede any options, actions or arguments thereto are parsed as *locations from which to start a search*. (The POSIX standard doesn't require that `find` operate at all when not passed at least one such location, though GNU's version does so anyhow by treating `.` as a default starting location if none are given).

When you instruct `find` to start from the same location twice by passing it two different paths that refer to the same place, you're thus telling it to run two separate searches starting at the same place -- so if the set of files doesn't change between when the first search runs and the second one, you get the same results twice.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that the first $pwd was also the starting path, I just thought that the output of pwd was being attached to the output of the normal find.

Comment: Right -- in `find .`, the starting path is `.`; in `find "$PWD"` (the case is important there -- only the all-caps name is filled out by the shell itself, whereas the lowercase form is [reserved for application/script use](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html)), the starting path is your current working directory as the shell understands its path to be; in `find /tmp`, the starting path is `/tmp`, etc. Without at least one path, there *is* no normal output to POSIX-standard `find`; only extended versions (like the GNU one) work in that mode at all.